# How to put RTSP video input in OpenCV

Tags: python, rtsp, openvino

I'm setting up a PPE Detection [module](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/safety-gear-detector-python) using OpenVINO in my Ubuntu 18.04. Although the video input worked well with my webcam `dev/video/0` but I wish it can be change to RTSP input. Whenever I put my RTSP Url inside the `config.json` it doesnt work and show me `Either wrong input path or empty line is found. Please check the conf.json file`.

**Here is the main.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import datetime
import json
from inference import Network

# Global vars
cpu_extension = ''
conf_modelLayers = ''
conf_modelWeights = ''
conf_safety_modelLayers = ''
conf_safety_modelWeights = ''
targetDevice = "CPU"
conf_batchSize = 1
conf_modelPersonLabel = 1
conf_inferConfidenceThreshold = 0.7
conf_inFrameViolationsThreshold = 19
conf_inFramePeopleThreshold = 5
use_safety_model = False
padding = 30
viol_wk = 0
acceptedDevices = ['CPU', 'GPU', 'MYRIAD', 'HETERO:FPGA,CPU', 'HDDL']
videos = []
name_of_videos = []
CONFIG_FILE = '../resources/config.json'
is_async_mode = True


class Video:
    def __init__(self, idx, path):
        if path.isnumeric():
            self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(int(path))
            self.name = "Cam " + str(idx)
        else:
            if os.path.exists(path):
                self.video = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://edwin:Passw0rd@192.168.0.144:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1")
                self.name = "Video " + str(idx)
            else:
                print("Either wrong input path or empty line is found. Please check the conf.json file")
                exit(21)
        if not self.video.isOpened():
            print("Couldn't open video: " + path)
            sys.exit(20)
        self.height = int(self.video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
        self.width = int(self.video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))

        self.currentViolationCount = 0
        self.currentViolationCountConfidence = 0
        self.prevViolationCount = 0
        self.totalViolations = 0
        self.totalPeopleCount = 0
        self.currentPeopleCount = 0
        self.currentPeopleCountConfidence = 0
        self.prevPeopleCount = 0
        self.currentTotalPeopleCount = 0

        cv2.namedWindow(self.name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        self.frame_start_time = datetime.datetime.now()


def get_args():
    """
    Parses the argument.
    :return: None
    """
    global is_async_mode
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--device",
                        help="Specify the target device to infer on; CPU, GPU,"
                             "FPGA, MYRIAD or HDDL is acceptable. Application will"
                             "look for a suitable plugin for device specified"
                             " (CPU by default)",
                        type=str, required=False)
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--model",
                        help="Path to an .xml file with a trained model's"
                             " weights.",
                        required=True, type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-sm", "--safety_model",
                        help="Path to an .xml file with a trained model's"
                             " weights.",
                        required=False, type=str, default=None)
    parser.add_argument("-e", "--cpu_extension",
                        help="MKLDNN (CPU)-targeted custom layers. Absolute "
                             "path to a shared library with the kernels impl",
                        type=str, default=None)
    parser.add_argument("-f", "--flag", help="sync or async", default="async", type=str)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    global conf_modelLayers, conf_modelWeights, conf_safety_modelLayers, conf_safety_modelWeights, \
        targetDevice, cpu_extension, videos, use_safety_model
    if args.model:
        conf_modelLayers = args.model
        conf_modelWeights = os.path.splitext(conf_modelLayers)[0] + ".bin"
    if args.safety_model:
        conf_safety_modelLayers = args.safety_model
        conf_safety_modelWeights = os.path.splitext(conf_safety_modelLayers)[0] + ".bin"
        use_safety_model = True
    if args.device:
        targetDevice = args.device
        if "MULTI:" not in targetDevice:
            if targetDevice not in acceptedDevices:
                print("Selected device, %s not supported." % (targetDevice))
                sys.exit(12)
    if args.cpu_extension:
        cpu_extension = args.cpu_extension
    if args.flag == "async":
        is_async_mode = True
        print('Application running in Async mode')
    else:
        is_async_mode = False
        print('Application running in Sync mode')
    assert os.path.isfile(CONFIG_FILE), "{} file doesn't exist".format(CONFIG_FILE)
    config = json.loads(open(CONFIG_FILE).read())
    for idx, item in enumerate(config['inputs']):
        vid = Video(idx, item['video'])
        name_of_videos.append([idx, item['video']])
        videos.append([idx, vid])


def detect_safety_hat(img):
    """
    Detection of the hat of the person.
    :param img: Current frame
    :return: Boolean value of the detected hat
    """
    lowH = 15
    lowS = 65
    lowV = 75

    highH = 30
    highS = 255
    highV = 255

    crop = 0
    height = 15
    perc = 8

    hsv = np.zeros(1)

    try:
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    except cv2.error as e:
        print("%d %d %d" % (img.shape))
        print("%d %d %d" % (img.shape))
        print(e)

    threshold_img = cv2.inRange(hsv, (lowH, lowS, lowV), (highH, highS, highV))

    x = 0
    y = int(threshold_img.shape[0] * crop / 100)
    w = int(threshold_img.shape[1])
    h = int(threshold_img.shape[0] * height / 100)
    img_cropped = threshold_img[y: y + h, x: x + w]

    if cv2.countNonZero(threshold_img) < img_cropped.size * perc / 100:
        return False
    return True


def detect_safety_jacket(img):
    """
    Detection of the safety jacket of the person.
    :param img: Current frame
    :return: Boolean value of the detected jacket
    """
    lowH = 0
    lowS = 150
    lowV = 42

    highH = 11
    highS = 255
    highV = 255

    crop = 15
    height = 40
    perc = 23

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    threshold_img = cv2.inRange(hsv, (lowH, lowS, lowV), (highH, highS, highV))

    x = 0
    y = int(threshold_img.shape[0] * crop / 100)
    w = int(threshold_img.shape[1])
    h = int(threshold_img.shape[0] * height / 100)
    img_cropped = threshold_img[y: y + h, x: x + w]

    if cv2.countNonZero(threshold_img) < img_cropped.size * perc / 100:
        return False
    return True


def detect_workers(workers, frame):
    """
    Detection of the person with the safety guards.
    :param workers: Total number of the person in the current frame
    :param frame: Current frame
    :return: Total violation count of the person
    """
    violations = 0
    global viol_wk
    for worker in workers:
        xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = worker
        crop = frame[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]
        if 0 not in crop.shape:
            if detect_safety_hat(crop):
                if detect_safety_jacket(crop):
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax),
                                  (0, 255, 0), 2)
                else:
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax),
                                  (0, 0, 255), 2)
                    violations += 1
                    viol_wk += 1

            else:
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (0, 0, 255), 2)
                violations += 1
                viol_wk += 1
    return violations


def main():
    """
    Load the network and parse the output.
    :return: None
    """
    get_args()
    global is_async_mode
    nextReq = 1
    currReq = 0
    nextReq_s = 1
    currReq_s = 0
    prevVideo = None
    vid_finished = [False] * len(videos)
    min_FPS = min([videos[i][1].video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS) for i in range(len(videos))])

    # Initialise the class
    infer_network = Network()
    infer_network_safety = Network()
    # Load the network to IE plugin to get shape of input layer
    plugin, (batch_size, channels, model_height, model_width) = \
        infer_network.load_model(conf_modelLayers, targetDevice, 1, 1, 2, cpu_extension)
    if use_safety_model:
        batch_size_sm, channels_sm, model_height_sm, model_width_sm = \
            infer_network_safety.load_model(conf_safety_modelLayers, targetDevice, 1, 1, 2, cpu_extension, plugin)[1]

    while True:
        for index, currVideo in videos:
            # Read image from video/cam
            vfps = int(round(currVideo.video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)))
            for i in range(0, int(round(vfps / min_FPS))):
                ret, current_img = currVideo.video.read()
                if not ret:
                    vid_finished[index] = True
                    break
            if vid_finished[index]:
                stream_end_frame = np.zeros((int(currVideo.height), int(currVideo.width), 1),
                                            dtype='uint8')
                cv2.putText(stream_end_frame, "Input file {} has ended".format
                (name_of_videos[index][1].split('/')[-1]),
                            (10, int(currVideo.height / 2)),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
                cv2.imshow(currVideo.name, stream_end_frame)
                continue
            # Transform image to person detection model input
            rsImg = cv2.resize(current_img, (model_width, model_height))
            rsImg = rsImg.transpose((2, 0, 1))
            rsImg = rsImg.reshape((batch_size, channels, model_height, model_width))

            infer_start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            # Infer current image
            if is_async_mode:
                infer_network.exec_net(nextReq, rsImg)
            else:
                infer_network.exec_net(currReq, rsImg)
                prevVideo = currVideo
                previous_img = current_img

            # Wait for previous request to end
            if infer_network.wait(currReq) == 0:
                infer_end_time = (datetime.datetime.now() - infer_start_time) * 1000

                in_frame_workers = []

                people = 0
                violations = 0
                hard_hat_detection = False
                vest_detection = False
                result = infer_network.get_output(currReq)
                # Filter output
                for obj in result[0][0]:
                    if obj[2] > conf_inferConfidenceThreshold:
                        xmin = int(obj[3] * prevVideo.width)
                        ymin = int(obj[4] * prevVideo.height)
                        xmax = int(obj[5] * prevVideo.width)
                        ymax = int(obj[6] * prevVideo.height)
                        xmin = int(xmin - padding) if (xmin - padding) > 0 else 0
                        ymin = int(ymin - padding) if (ymin - padding) > 0 else 0
                        xmax = int(xmax + padding) if (xmax + padding) < prevVideo.width else prevVideo.width
                        ymax = int(ymax + padding) if (ymax + padding) < prevVideo.height else prevVideo.height
                        cv2.rectangle(previous_img, (xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                        people += 1
                        in_frame_workers.append((xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax))
                        new_frame = previous_img[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]
                        if use_safety_model:

                            # Transform image to safety model input
                            in_frame_sm = cv2.resize(new_frame, (model_width_sm, model_height_sm))
                            in_frame_sm = in_frame_sm.transpose((2, 0, 1))
                            in_frame_sm = in_frame_sm.reshape(
                                (batch_size_sm, channels_sm, model_height_sm, model_width_sm))

                            infer_start_time_sm = datetime.datetime.now()
                            if is_async_mode:
                                infer_network_safety.exec_net(nextReq_s, in_frame_sm)
                            else:
                                infer_network_safety.exec_net(currReq_s, in_frame_sm)
                            # Wait for the result
                            infer_network_safety.wait(currReq_s)
                            infer_end_time_sm = (datetime.datetime.now() - infer_start_time_sm) * 1000

                            result_sm = infer_network_safety.get_output(currReq_s)
                            # Filter output
                            hard_hat_detection = False
                            vest_detection = False
                            detection_list = []
                            for obj_sm in result_sm[0][0]:

                                if (obj_sm[2] > 0.4):
                                    # Detect safety vest
                                    if (int(obj_sm[1])) == 2:
                                        xmin_sm = int(obj_sm[3] * (xmax - xmin))
                                        ymin_sm = int(obj_sm[4] * (ymax - ymin))
                                        xmax_sm = int(obj_sm[5] * (xmax - xmin))
                                        ymax_sm = int(obj_sm[6] * (ymax - ymin))
                                        if vest_detection == False:
                                            detection_list.append(
                                                [xmin_sm + xmin, ymin_sm + ymin, xmax_sm + xmin, ymax_sm + ymin])
                                            vest_detection = True

                                    # Detect hard-hat
                                    if int(obj_sm[1]) == 4:
                                        xmin_sm_v = int(obj_sm[3] * (xmax - xmin))
                                        ymin_sm_v = int(obj_sm[4] * (ymax - ymin))
                                        xmax_sm_v = int(obj_sm[5] * (xmax - xmin))
                                        ymax_sm_v = int(obj_sm[6] * (ymax - ymin))
                                        if hard_hat_detection == False:
                                            detection_list.append([xmin_sm_v + xmin, ymin_sm_v + ymin, xmax_sm_v + xmin,
                                                                   ymax_sm_v + ymin])
                                            hard_hat_detection = True

                            if hard_hat_detection is False or vest_detection is False:
                                violations += 1
                            for _rect in detection_list:
                                cv2.rectangle(current_img, (_rect[0], _rect[1]), (_rect[2], _rect[3]), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                            if is_async_mode:
                                currReq_s, nextReq_s = nextReq_s, currReq_s

                        # Use OpenCV if worker-safety-model is not provided
                        else:
                            violations = detect_workers(in_frame_workers, previous_img)

                # Check if detected violations equals previous frames
                if violations == prevVideo.currentViolationCount:
                    prevVideo.currentViolationCountConfidence += 1

                    # If frame threshold is reached, change validated count
                    if prevVideo.currentViolationCountConfidence == conf_inFrameViolationsThreshold:

                        # If another violation occurred, save image
                        if prevVideo.currentViolationCount > prevVideo.prevViolationCount:
                            prevVideo.totalViolations += (
                                        prevVideo.currentViolationCount - prevVideo.prevViolationCount)
                        prevVideo.prevViolationCount = prevVideo.currentViolationCount
                else:
                    prevVideo.currentViolationCountConfidence = 0
                    prevVideo.currentViolationCount = violations

                # Check if detected people count equals previous frames
                if people == prevVideo.currentPeopleCount:
                    prevVideo.currentPeopleCountConfidence += 1

                    # If frame threshold is reached, change validated count
                    if prevVideo.currentPeopleCountConfidence == conf_inFrameViolationsThreshold:
                        prevVideo.currentTotalPeopleCount += (
                                prevVideo.currentPeopleCount - prevVideo.prevPeopleCount)
                        if prevVideo.currentTotalPeopleCount > prevVideo.prevPeopleCount:
                            prevVideo.totalPeopleCount += prevVideo.currentTotalPeopleCount - prevVideo.prevPeopleCount
                        prevVideo.prevPeopleCount = prevVideo.currentPeopleCount
                else:
                    prevVideo.currentPeopleCountConfidence = 0
                    prevVideo.currentPeopleCount = people

                frame_end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                cv2.putText(previous_img, 'Total people count: ' + str(
                    prevVideo.totalPeopleCount), (10, prevVideo.height - 10),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
                cv2.putText(previous_img, 'Current people count: ' + str(
                    prevVideo.currentTotalPeopleCount),
                            (10, prevVideo.height - 40),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
                cv2.putText(previous_img, 'Total violation count: ' + str(
                    prevVideo.totalViolations), (10, prevVideo.height - 70),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
                cv2.putText(previous_img, 'FPS: %0.2fs' % (1 / (
                        frame_end_time - prevVideo.frame_start_time).total_seconds()),
                            (10, prevVideo.height - 100),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
                cv2.putText(previous_img, "Inference time: N\A for async mode" if is_async_mode else \
                    "Inference time: {:.3f} ms".format((infer_end_time).total_seconds()),
                            (10, prevVideo.height - 130),
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)

                cv2.imshow(prevVideo.name, previous_img)
                prevVideo.frame_start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            # Swap
            if is_async_mode:
                currReq, nextReq = nextReq, currReq
                previous_img = current_img
                prevVideo = currVideo
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
                print("Attempting to stop input files")
                infer_network.clean()
                infer_network_safety.clean()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                return

        if False not in vid_finished:
            infer_network.clean()
            infer_network_safety.clean()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Here is the config file**

```
{
     "inputs": [
        {
           "video": "rtsp://xxx:xxx@192.168.0.144:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1"
        }
     ]
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the line `if os.path.exists(path):`. This `if` condition checks if `path` points towards an existing file. Your RTSP stream not being a file, it leads to your error.

For example, you can modify this condition to:

```py
if os.path.exists(path) or path.startswith("rtsp"):
```

By the way, your hard-coded the rtsp stream address within the code, so it will not use your configured path. You may want to replace the hard-coded path with `path`.

Comment: Thanks ! , btw is the `startswith` have a specific arguments? Example like rtsp etc ? Or i can `startwith` with any filename that I like?

Comment: `startswith` is a generic string method in Python, check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith